# how to have table in the middle of div vertically

Tags: css

This is surprisingly hard to find out how to do. All solutions I've found so far have been wrong. Here's my problem:

I have a table in a div:

```
<div id="dishreel">
    <table>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I'm putting images inside it:

```
for(var i=0; i<allDishes.length; i++){
    var td = document.createElement("td");

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("dishimg");
    img.src = "images/"+allDishes[i].image;

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(allDishes[i].name);
    p.appendChild(text);

    td.append(img);
    td.append(p);
    dishreel.find("tr").append(td);
}
```

All of the dishes end up on a row, like this:

[image]

This is what I want. Now, I want the row of dishes to be in the middle of the div, vertically. So a row in the middle of the page in this case, since the div is taking up all of the page, because of my css:

```
#dishreel{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

I've tried to use flexbox, it didn't change anything:

```
#dishreel{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Does somebody know how to get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: add `align-items:center`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: Temani, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Sandi are you sure you set 100% height on the body also ?

Answer (score -1):

I think flexbox didn't work because you have a single item inside #dishreel: a table. hav you tried giving the table a class with flexbox display?

```
#dishreel {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}


.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

<div id="dishreel">
    <table class="wrap">
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to make the margin right/left auto for the table:

```
table {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Then make the width 100% for the td:

```
td {
  width: 100%;
}
```